# primefaces tabView skip the form validation when tab change

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, onchange, tabview

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.3 and Mojarra 2.17.

I have a page that contains a `p:tabView`. The second tab contains a textbox and `required="true"`. When I navigate from the second tab to first tab, it will validate the textbox is empty and display an error message (I have a `PhaseListener` class to display the error in global `p:messages`). How to skip this validation?

I can't found any solutions in:

- http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3423
- http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4143

and I do not want to use PrimeFaces `p:wizard`.

My tabView.xhtml:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="false" activeIndex="0" >  
      <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{test.onTabChange}"/> 
      <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab1">
        <ui:include src="#{test.tab1}"></ui:include>
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab2">  
        <ui:include src="#{test.tab2}"></ui:include>
      </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

In my Java class:

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {              
     this.setTab1("tab1.xhtml");
     this.setTab2("tab2.xhtml"）;
 }
```

My tab1.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form1">    
    <p:messages globalOnly="true" />
    tab1 page
    <br/>
</h:form>
```

My tab2.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form2">
    <p:messages globalOnly="true" />
    <p>
        tab2 page
    </p>
    <p:inputText id="txt1" required="true" />
    <p:message for="txt1" display="text" />
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="@form" />
</h:form>
```

My PhaseListener class:

```
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent e) {
        if (e.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS) {
            if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size() > 0) {
                String number = String.valueOf(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size());
                String errorMsg = "there are " + number + " errors.";
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMsg,
                                errorMsg));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With your current setup, you don't have that many options. One thing you can do is to make the `required` attribute conditional using an EL expression

Comment: @kolossus, can you please explain more? my current setup still need what options? and how to make the required attribute conditional using an EL expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the code:
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
under TabChangeEvent method in backign bean..

eg:

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {              
  this.setTab1("tab1.xhtml");
  this.setTab2("tab2.xhtml"）;
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `immediate="true"` attribute in your ajax event tag. This will prevent your fields to be validated, and just your listener will be called:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{test.onTabChange}" immediate="true"/>
```

Comment: Is error message just stays from some previous submit or it shows when ju change tab?

Comment: Try to add `process="@none"` as well in `p:ajax`.

Comment: if add process="@none", then the tab change is not working.
if process="@this", the error still exist.

Comment: I think the issue relies more on how tabView handles tab change. `<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{test.onTabChange}" immediate="true"/>` just listesn and do not manage the tab change